# Copy to clipboard button for Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I embedded a Powerpoint slide to Sharepoint. It is some kind of guide where you can click on stuff and go back with hyperlinks. There is a front page where you can click hyperlinks to go to slides A, B and C. Unfortunately embedded slides do not allow CTRL C. I would like to create a Powerpoint macro and then assign this to a button, where clicking would copy the TextA on Slide A to user's clipboard.

I tried recording macro on excel and then using it on Powerpoint and it did not work. I'm also curious even if I got the right code for the macro, would it work on an embedded slide? Hyperlinks work.

Comment: Can you include your code?

Comment: Don't laugh, but I used this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.textrange.copy

Comment: This example copies the text in shape one on slide one in the active presentation to the Clipboard.

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Copy